# I2C communication with Wire.h(ESP32)

Tags: i2c

I trying to connect with nitric oxide sensor over I2C bus. I'm using Wire.h library.
http://semeatech.com/uploads/SensorModule/7-Smart_EN-v1.0.pdf <- Aplication note

My code:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x0B);
Wire.write(0x00);
Wire.write(0x01);
byte err = Wire.endTransmission(false);
Wire.requestFrom(0x0B, 3);
while(Wire.available()){
//Read data
}
```

Sensor returns msb = 0, lsb = 0 and checkSum = 255
Am I doing something wrong with I2C bus?

Comment: The checksum of the reading is valid. Are you sure your NO2 concentration is within the range of the sensor? Or does the sensor need to be running for some time until the measurements are accurate?

Comment: Yes I'm sure the measurement should be diffrent than zero. But when im trying to read temperature(change 0x01 to 0x02) it response with values over 200°C. Thats why I'm thinking something is wrong with my I2C communication

Comment: If the checksum is ok, it's a strong indication that the I2C communication is ok. Have you divided the temperature value by 100 as required?

Comment: Yes, it's response something like 0xD9, 0x32 -> 0xD932 -> 55602 -> 556,02°C

Comment: I was thinking about 7-bit addresses in I2C. If sensor addres is 0x0B should I send data to 0x16 and recive it from 0x017?(0x0B <<1 == 0x16)

Comment: No, your code is correct. The Arduino Core shifts the address to the left by 1 bit and then sets the R/W bit. You specify the same address for reading and writing. So 0x0b should result in the NO2 bit pattern shown in the data sheet.